# black sprite on jni callback

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I've made simple helper class in c++ to call native methods from android.

My c++ function:

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_imagePicked(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring filename);
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_imagePicked(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring filename){
    std::string str = JniHelper::jstring2string(filename);
    auto helper = NativeHelper::getInstance();
    if(helper->imagePickedCallback != NULL){
        helper->imagePickedCallback(str);
    }
}
```

Callback implementation:

```
void HelloWorld::imagePicked(string filename){
    CCLOG("image picked: %s", filename.c_str());
    txtStatus->setString("Image picked: " + filename);
    if(FileUtils::getInstance()->isFileExist(filename)){
        auto sprite = Sprite::create(filename);
        addChild(sprite);
        sprite->setPosition(960 * rand_0_1(), 640 * rand_0_1());
        sprite->setScale(0.1);
    }
    else{
        CCLOG("File does not exist!");
    }
}
```

It just loads an image, scales it to 10% and place a random position on screen. I also can see CCLOG.

Finally java implementation:

```
public static native void imagePicked(String filename);

public static void showImagePicker(){
        _appActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                _appActivity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }

        });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             final String path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
             Cocos2dxHelper.runOnGLThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imagePicked(path);
                }
            });
         }
    }
}
```

Before I was just directly calling imagePicked from uithread, but I found that opengl is not thread safe and it should be done on glthread.

Anyway doing it that way calls a callback, sprite appears with correct size on randomized position on screen, but it's pure black. Ui text also becomes black (after calling setString). I also made a test and called this method just from HelloWorld::init function with hardcoded filename and it works without any problem (image appears and text also works). So it's definietly an issue with threading. But I'm using runOnGLThread so it should work. I've also read some plugin source codes (in-app purchase) and it's done the same way.

I also found method in scheduler named 'performFunctionInCocosThread', however I cannot make it working:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_imagePicked(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring filename){
    std::string str = JniHelper::jstring2string(filename);
    auto helper = NativeHelper::getInstance();
    if(helper->imagePickedCallback != NULL && helper->scheduler != NULL){
        helper->scheduler->performFunctionInCocosThread([&](){
            helper->imagePickedCallback(str);
        });
    }
}
```

(scheduler is set by HelloWorld - getScheduler(), I also tried director->getScheduler()). It crashes app with signal 11 (and with signal 6 when calling jni directly - without runOnGLThread).

Any help will be appreciated,
Regards

Comment: I made a workaround using runAction and CallFunc, but I want to know why runOnGLThread doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x thread is not quite GL thread - at least in Android as far as I know. For example, see [this discussion](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/4401) between Cocos2dx authors.

For your purpose, you can get rid of the `runOnGLThread` and move the threading to the C++ side by this function:

```
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread(/*a function here*/)
```